# Connecting two transformers of equal rating to recharge a battery

Tags: batteries

I have two transformers having capacity 6-0-6(volt) & 0.5amp each.
However, my battery requires 6v & 1amp. How can I connect two transformers to get my battery charged?

Answer (score 3):

If what you are saying is that your transformers are each rated at 12V (with a center tap) @ 0.5A, you can put a full-wave rectifier on just one of them and pull 1A @ 6V from the output. The average current through each half of the secondary won't exceed the 0.5A rating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkPxvB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The output will be nearly 8V DC and this may be OK with the battery the OP wishes to charge?

Comment: Without a filter capacitor, the average DC output will actually be about 6Vrms*1.414*0.637 - 0.7V = 4.7V, with peaks to about 7.8V. Should be fine.

Comment: Wasn't there some rule of thumb how maximum current decreases with a rectifier, just like how effective voltage increases? In the end Power should be the same.

Comment: What about the RMS current that heats the wire ?Its the average current that charges the battery.

Answer (score 1):

Because you will need to rectify any secondary voltage of a transformer in your application and, you might also need a regulator circuit to provide the correct DC level, I propose that you wire the secondaries of the two transformers in series and use a single bridge rectifier and a step-down (buck) SMPSU. Primaries in parallel.

It's not good practise to wire secondaries in parallel because one may be mismatched to the other and lead to self-heating complications and power-loss.

Wiring the secondaries in series to produce 0 - 6 - 12 - 18 - 24V tappings seems sensible to me. After the rectifier (connected to 0 and 24), the peak DC voltage will be about 32V and this should be smoothed with a capacitor.

There are plenty of buck regulators that will step this down to 6V - watch out for the peak voltage they can work with though - several buck regulators have maximum peak voltages specified at 36V and this isn't enough for reliable operation without failure. Choose one greater than 40V peak input level.